# Getting remote file contents after login with cURL

Tags: php, curl

As the title suggest, I'm trying to get back the content of (several) pages on a site that requires a login.  This is a legitimate login and I have access to the content - nothing shady's going on.

I've searched SO and found several posters attempting the same thing - nothing I've found has helped with this specific issue.

I've tried several variations - adding various options like FOLLOWLOCATION (set to true, then tried set to false); increasing the timeout; setting both COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE; calling curl_close after the login, then a new curl_init after (before loading the target file); using traditional PHP methods to grab the file (file_get_contents, etc); explicitly creating the cookie file and setting it to writable; tried with and without REFERER; tried changing up the REFERER; tried both http and https protocols; tried calling curl_close once first to force the cookie to be written, then running the script block again immediately afterward; etc...  No luck.

Below is a snapshot of the code being used (just trying to get one file for now).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
$e = curl_init();
curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.some-site.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=bob&password=1234');
curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.some-site.com');
curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($e);

curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.some-site.com/posts.php?id=1');
$content = curl_exec($e);

print htmlentities($content);

curl_close($e);
```

There is no actual error - cURL is working like it should, but $content is set to the "You're not signed in...  Please login now..." page.

After logging in via browser (Fx, Chrome, Safari, IE), each post can be accessed (again, through the browser) without issue.

I'm stumped.

TYIA for any suggestions - LMK if any additional info would be helpful.

Comment: is `https://www.some-site.com/login.php` the actual submission script to where username and password are POSTed?

Comment: @tradyblix - yes, it's the action of the login form - assume the login form is http://www.some-site.com/login.html.  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: if you do `$content = curl_exec($e);` and dump `$content` on your first request (login.php), what do you get?

Comment: @tradyblix - no output.  after trying that, i added FOLLOWLOCATION in case there was a redirect, but still - no output.  that led me to create a local copy of the HTML form and submit, which does redirect to either an 'already logged in...' page, or optionally a redirect specified in the form action as a GET variable (login.php?redirect=somepage.php

Comment: @Big MoMo - Try adding `curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7) AppleWebKit/534.48.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.48.3');` as some things expect a user-agent string to be specified and `curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` so you can see the request and response headers. See if anything is odd. Also, try outputting the result of the first `curl_exec($e);` to the screen so you can make sure the login was indeed successful.

Comment: @Big MoMo: maybe if you're not getting anything from the first (if I understood correctly), the cookie never get correctly set in the jar? Did the authentication cookie appear inside cookie.txt ?

Comment: @Francois Deschenes - tried both, no difference.  the output of the first attempt (the login) comes back empty - i'm pretty sure that's where the issue is, but haven't figured out how to get around it.

Comment: @St0rM - you're correct - there is nothing in the cookie.  i think we've narrowed it down to the login as the point of failure, but again no idea why.  AFAICT from the original form, it just takes user and pass via post (no other inputs, except some obviously there for client-side validation).  perhaps i'll include those as well tomorrow and see if that works.  thanks for the comment

Comment: @Big MoMo - That could be the problem indeed. Did you try adding `curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` as others have suggested above? When you added the verbose option, it should have outputted the request and response headers. Did anything stand out? It's difficult to help without being able to test the "real thing". I would focus on trying to get something back from the login attempt first.

Answer (score 4):

**This is I'm using to get page content after logged into the site.**

```
$login_url = 'http://www.examplesite.com/php/login.php';

//These are the post data username and password
$post_data = 'loginuser=smith&loginpass=sh20147';

//Create a curl object
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the useragent
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

//This is a POST query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

//Set the post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

//We want the content after the query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



//Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

/*
Set the cookie storing files
Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//Execute the action to login
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($postResult);
```

**After logged, now get the logged page or specific page contents as following.**

```
 $url = 'http://www.examplesite.com/members/home.php';


curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url ,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
```

[More details](http://webexplorar.com/php-remote-submit-a-form-and-get-result-using-curl/)